# How can I get the website menu bar to stay in one line?

Tags: css

I am building a site, and hanged on a problem.
I positioned the menu bar perfectly, but for some reason on bigger display resolutions or android devices the Contact Us menu item tends to jump to a new line.
The link of the web page is http://uk.delux.lv Just try to zoom it and see what happens.
This is the css for menu:

```
#topmenu_wrap {
    margin:auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #fff;
}

#topmenu {
    background-color: #fff;
    width:966px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #969696;
}
```

Comment: looking at it right now in firefox the contact us link is already on a newline without zooming.

Comment: If I take off the left and right borders it jumps up to on one line.  When thinking of widths you have to take into account border widths with the total widths

Comment: I removed the borders, and it is now in one line for a few more resolutions. I think I can fix it up even more by decreasing the padding on both sides, however, as the menu becomes shorter, it loses the design side and does not look so good. Is it possible to add a dark background that is in same width ad the slideshow?

Comment: I was starting to make a recommendation, but then it appears that the site fixed itself.  Did you just make a change?

Comment: set the width of the topnav ul to 966px to make the ul the same width as everything else

Comment: I don't think I want the menu bar shorter, I want it to keep the 966px width as it is now, but I would like if it would rather expand horizontally not start a new line. Any way to make this happen?

Comment: What was your recommendation selbie? I made it the width it was before, but removed the borders since I discovered it looks better. But there is still a question. Is it possible for the menu to expand horizontally not start a new line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make css menu width impossible to change when zooming or changing resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318036/how-to-make-css-menu-width-impossible-to-change-when-zooming-or-changing-resolut)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest is to set the padding of the a tags in the ul>li to `padding: 16px 15px`.  Set the total width of the topnav>ul with class menu to `width: 966px`.

You are not going to be able to control the width of the text on the topnav unless you make them images.  That will allow the text to remain the same no matter how far the user zooms or the size they set the text in their browser.

I thought I found somewhere a while ago a way to set the text as static so when someone zoomed nothing happened but I can't find it.

As far as making it expand I wouldn't do that.  You aren't going to be able to control every persons browser and the way it looks.  Where I work we only check a normal view in the 5 major browsers and if they change something on their end then oh well.